# An inequality in the proof of Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem in Royden's book.

Tags: real-analysis

In the proof of the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, Royden used the following equality,

$$\liminf\int_X[g - f_n] \, d\mu = \int_X g \, d\mu - \limsup \int_X f_n \, d\mu$$

How do you justify this statement?
This seems very strange, isn't this equality equivalent to $\liminf \int_X f_n = \limsup \int_X f_n$?

Attached is the original texts. (p.378, Real Analysis by Royden 4th edition)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If $a=\int gd\mu$ and $a_n=\int f_nd \mu$ then $\lim \inf \, [a-a_n]=a-\lim \inf (-a_n)=a-\lim\sup a_n$.